# pdo_mysql extension is not installed in sublime text editor

Tags: mysql, php, sublime-text

[image: ine]

I have found some problems i don't know what was this.
  please read carefully and give some solution.

Comment: Have you installed `php7.2_mysql` (or a similar package for your PHP version)?

Comment: nope install php7.2_mysql